Calculate the last $3$ digits of $2008^{2007^{2006^{\cdots^{2^{1}}}}}\\$.
This problem is originally from PuMAC$^{a}$ $2007$. I tried using modular arithmetic (Euler's totient function$(\phi)$) but could not solve more than this:
I calculated Euler's totient functions separately by the formula $\phi(n)=n\big(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\big)\big(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\big)\cdots\big(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\big),$ and then I worked them with $\pmod{1000}.$
But it looks very tedious!
I used the property that when $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime we have
$a^b\equiv a^{b\mod{\phi(n)}}$ $\mod{n}$
It then suffices to calculate $b\mod{\phi(n)}$.
After this I have not been able to proceed further so I am hoping for someone's help at the moment. Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

These power towers tend to stabilize pretty quickly. Only the first few lower levels matter; the rest doesn't.

Can you give the solution, I'm dying for it.

I can't. Rules are rules.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

FYI, I found the duplicate by looking through the list of linked questions of Modular exponentiation by hand ($a^b\bmod c$).

FYI again, an Approach0 search comes up not only with the duplicate question, but also your same specific problem in the AoPS thread Powers powers powers too much of powers. Note, also, this site has quite a few closely related questions.

See mod order reduciton for general methods for computation of large modular powers. $\ \ $

Hint: Use CRT. Let $N$ be the given number then $N\ \mathrm{mod}\ 8$ and $N\ \mathrm{mod}\ 125$ determine $N\ \mathrm{mod}\ 1000$. In your case, $N\ \mathrm{mod}\ 8$ is just $0$ and for modulo $125$, you want to look at the exponent modulo $\phi(125)=100$. Then, you can repeat a similar thing.
Hope this helps. :)

I tried it and couldn't reach to a conclusion, if you don't mind can you post the solution?

@NOTACID Just repeat the idea: For $2008^{2007^{2006^\cdots}}\bmod{1000}$, the remainder $\bmod 8$ is clear and it suffices to find $2008^{2007^{2006^\cdots}}\bmod{125}$. For the latter, you need $2007^{2006^{2005^\cdots}}\bmod{100}$. i.e., $\bmod 4$ and $\bmod{25}$. For the latter, you need $2006^{2005^{2004^\cdots}}\bmod{20}$, i.e., $\bmod 4$ (easy) and $\bmod 5$. For the latter, sou need $2005^{2004^{2003^\cdots}}\bmod{4}$, which is easy.

Let's look at a simpler example: what is the last digit of $8^{7^{6^{\cdots^{2^{1}}}}}$?
Well, using the mentioned property:
$$\begin{align}8^{7^{6^{\cdots^{2^{1}}}}}\mod 10 &\equiv 8\hat{}\left({7^{6^{\cdots^{2}}}\mod\varphi(10)}\right)\mod 10 \equiv\tag1\\
&\equiv 8\hat{}\left({7^{6^{\cdots^{2}}}\mod4}\right)\mod 10\equiv\tag2\\
&\equiv8\hat{}\left({7\hat{}\left({6^{5^{\cdots^{2}}}}\mod 2\right)\mod4}\right)\mod 10\equiv\tag3\\
&\equiv 8\hat{}\left({7^0\mod4}\right)\mod 10\equiv\tag4\\
&\equiv8^1\mod 10\equiv8\end{align}$$
